# Allow specific products to be purchased only if a coupon is applied in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, coupon

I am working on a woocommerce website and I am trying to restrict a product to be purchased only if a coupon is applied for it, so it should not be processed without adding a coupon code. User must enter a coupon code to be able to order this specific product (not on all other products).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For defined products, the following code will not allow checkout if a coupon is not applied, displaying an error message:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'mandatory_coupon_for_specific_items' );
function mandatory_coupon_for_specific_items() {
    $targeted_ids   = array(37); // The targeted product ids (in this array)
    $coupon_code    = 'summer2'; // The required coupon code

    $coupon_applied = in_array( strtolower($coupon_code), WC()->cart->get_applied_coupons() );

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        // Check cart item for defined product Ids and applied coupon
        if( in_array( $cart_item['product_id'], $targeted_ids ) && ! $coupon_applied ) {
            wc_clear_notices(); // Clear all other notices

            // Avoid checkout displaying an error notice
            wc_add_notice( sprintf( 'The product"%s" requires a coupon for checkout.', $cart_item['data']->get_name() ), 'error' );
            break; // stop the loop
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

**And in checkout:**

[image]

Comment: i added this in function.php and then created a coupon for a specific product, but it proceed to checkout without coupon code? am i doing it wrong?

Comment: @ZainAli I have tested again this code and it works perfectly… So it seems that you have not set the correct product ID or coupon code.

Comment: ok 1 more question this is only for 1 product so if i want to put this condition on another product so do i have to copy paste this function or what?

Comment: @ZainAli No you can add as any product ids (integers) as you want in the array like:  `$targeted_ids = array(37, 52, 63);`

Comment: ok one last thing to ask if i want the coupon from what i have added from woocommerce how can i do that? instead of $coupon_code    = 'summer2'; i want it to find coupon from panel. can we do that?

Comment: question posted

Comment: yes i was just applying it, it works and it worked greatly thank you :)

Comment: @LoicTheAztec do you or anyone know how to add multiple coupon codes in 
`$coupon_code = 'summer2';` This doesnt work: `$coupon_code = array('test-zvojrmtg6f','test-0meujlatns');`