# Additional Details while ordering on woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on a woocommerce system in which I want to allow users to buy products only if they have a reference number with them and is entered into the cart page/checkout page.

The reference numbers are list of numbers which are predefined and are present in database.

How to achieve this in Wordpress woocommerce

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are looking at something like this

[Products based on coupon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56094263/allow-specific-products-to-be-purchase-only-if-a-coupon-is-applied-in-woocommerc)

So here you can apply coupon in check out field. You can add the reference numbers as coupons in back end.